# Typing React components in Flow when passing a component as a prop

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I want to pass a React component as input prop to another React component. I tried to reference it as React.Component<*, *, *> but when I use the passed component in the render method I get an error. This is how I wrote out my flow code.

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Input = props => <div>Yo</div>

type DefaultProps = {
  InputComponent: Input
};

type Props = {
  InputComponent: React.Component<*, *, *>
};

class App extends Component<DefaultProps, Props, void> {
  static defaultProps = {
    InputComponent: Input
  };

  props: Props;

  render() {
    const { InputComponent } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <InputComponent />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

However in the App render method I get the error

```
React element `InputComponent` (Expected React component instead of React$Component)
```

How should I properly type input components?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since v0.59.0, you should use React.Component. For example:

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

const Input = props => <div>Yo</div>

type Props = {
  InputComponent: React.Component<*, *>
};

class App extends React.Component<Props, void> {
  static defaultProps = {
    InputComponent: Input
  };

  render() {
    const { InputComponent } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <InputComponent />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjYqfOLMAcn0pqYG50q4A7AZ2IBJXjgCuxALxgc9HPzCSAfGAA8AEwwA3JQE04q4Jp3pCATxxkwABTkLpAb1RgwI8YQDCDPLzK9CAFykbIQAdF64fH6EqiAANMhKqAC+XKhUMBT8CgCCODhgZAAehH7qCuTUYRE+0aq2cPIJWnAY6ipOLoIUhBhUYOpkUBRiMIQN8opgnS6uohI1Uf5BbhLOYKnoLqy8g-gAFACU0+suPALEDnPui77+G1OEABYY-KGyjfxbs6yEYvi8MD7U6zDTaJKzSFqVaebxLYjACFQwzGJEuQ7rZIpVBAA) for 0.59.0. As mentioned in the comments, there is [a description of the changes here](https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627).

**:: Before v0.59.0 ::**

You should use `ReactClass<*>` instead of `React.Component`.

Here is a [working example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVpK0ctqCWAtgA5wBOALmAEoCmAhgMYUA0YA3mAMJwlwB2tflQC+YKGV5gA5GQbNpAbgJ9KNeRQAiAeQCy4yYRlymFALQATXkvSMBAZyoBJfsQCuVALxhik4vbBPAD4wAB4LfAA3IIBNOFDgCOj0CgBPYlowTVooejcYCgAFPwDvdlQwMBd3Ch4+QWEALirXD1QRZVQ0jLBiuH9AjgqWmrrSBopmulMuGHp7e1CQIPbOxjmFsABBYmIwWgAPCiELALGBIQpQ7Nz8opK2Pv82SLh8CxDyysd6CnxGMAWHJ5ApPUpDSqVaoec4TZrQijDDroSq+fr2ZpgzqVOT8IFkAAUAEoIZC7PxHBwRjDeONLmAxN4KAALfD2AB0aP8KMhcgobjI-DABOGkLCSRWYrFoQRsPpwElUoSEtFYCJSPaqCAA), and the documentation is [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.44.1/lib/react.js#L96)!

```
/**
 * Type of a React class (not to be confused with the type of instances of a
 * React class, which is the React class itself). A React class is any subclass
 * of React$Component. We make the type of a React class parametric over Config,
 * which is derived from some of the type parameters (DefaultProps, Props) of
 * React$Component, abstracting away others (State); whereas a React$Component
 * type is useful for checking the definition of a React class, a ReactClass
 * type (and the corresponding React$Element type, see below) is useful for
 * checking the uses of a React class. The required constraints are set up using
 * a "helper" type alias, that takes an additional type parameter C representing
 * the React class, which is then abstracted with an existential type (*). The *
 * can be thought of as an "auto" instruction to the typechecker, telling it to
 * fill in the type from context.
 */
type ReactClass<Config> = _ReactClass<*, *, Config, *>;
type _ReactClass<DefaultProps, Props, Config: $Diff<Props, DefaultProps>, C: React$Component<DefaultProps, Props, any>> = Class<C>;
```

Comment: The example doesn't seem to be working any longer, and I'm unable to find anything about `ReactClass` in the docs. Is it possible that this question applies to an older version of flow?

Comment: Indeed, it appears ReactClass was removed: https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/20a5d7dbf484699b47008656583b57e6016cfa0b#diff-5ca8a047db3f6ee8d65a46bba4471236L136

Comment: It looks like now the type is React.ComponentType<Props>. Here is I guess what you might call documentation of the change: https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/20a5d7dbf484699b47008656583b57e6016cfa0b#diff-5ca8a047db3f6ee8d65a46bba4471236L136

Comment: It looks like now React Components should simply be React.Component, but I haven't tested the new version.

Comment: This also looks like good context for the shift: https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627

Comment: @AndiDev feel free to edit my answer - I haven't been using Flow in a while.

Answer (score 0):

On version Flow 0.93.0, you can do the following.

```
    import type { Element as ReactElement } from 'react';

    type Props = {
      component: ReactElement
    }
```